# Flutter _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get data from json but I can't.

```
var url =
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Izmir&appid=$apikey&units=metric";

List<GetWeather> waitems = [];

Future getItems() async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

  for (var eachItem in jsonData) {
    final items = GetWeather(
      weather: eachItem['weather'],
    );

    waitems.add(items);
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnsOO.png)

I want to save the data I get from the API to the list and use it later, but I can't.

Comment: please can you show which type of response structure are you getting from this API??

Comment: Looks like response.body is not a list, could you please paste the response.body?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your returned jsonData to be a `Map<String, dynamic>`. so to iterate that, try

```
jsonData.forEach((key,value) {

});
```

Depending on what your jsonData is, you might need to just take the value or `value['weather']`....or something else, I can't say.